# Grouping persons by age

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This is the `PersonAgeGroup` class:

```
public class PersonAgeGroup
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Person other)) return false;

        return other.Name.Equals(Name) && other.Age.Equals(Age);
    }
}
```

So the intention is to group a list of `Person` by their age into a list of `PersonAgeGroup`, and I got this so far, but I'm stuck. `ages.ToList()` gives the wrong list type into the `PersonAgeGroup` list:

```
public IList<PersonAgeGroup> GroupPersonsByAge(List<Person> persons)
{
    var results = from person in persons
        group person by person.Age
        into ages
        select new {Age = ages.Key, Persons = ages.ToList()};
    //Tip: use the "ToList" extension method to convert an IEnumerable to a List
    IList<PersonAgeGroup> people = results.ToList();
    return people;
}
```

Comment: You're stuck in what? You need to describe the issues that you're having. Also in the last line you're returning `null`, aren't you supposed to return the results instead?

Comment: Are you getting an error or something? What isn't working? You are returning null

Comment: the return null statement was just so i could try and play my other tests at first because i kept getting compilation errors.

stuck as in Persons = ages.ToList() returns the wrong list

Comment: I've never understood why beginners make an "age" property on "person" classes. Your age constantly changes; make a "date of birth" property and then you don't have to constantly update the object.

Comment: @EricLippert It's not a beginners' mistake. The `Person` list in this case is a group of women at the age of 25, so the age stays at 25 and will never change :P. But for men where your comment applies, your assumption that the data was stored like that might be incorrect. The data could be stored with DOB and the code then populates the list with age calculated from the DOB. I don't see anything wrong with that as long as the list is just a temporary one. It's better to keep the DOB and only calculate the age when needed, but in certain scenarios doing it upfront can be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group by age and then select and map each group to `PersonAgeGroup`:

```
var reuslt = persons.GroupBy(p => p.Age)
                .Select(grp => new PersonAgeGroup { Age = grp.Key, Persons = grp});
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you should not return `null`. Second, instead of `anonymous object`, create an instance of PersonAgeGroup in your select statement

For Example,

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x=>x.Age)
                 .Select(x=> new PersonAgeGroup
                          {
                             Age= x.Key, 
                             Persons = x.ToList()
                           });
```

Your method would be (eliminating the result variable)

```
public IList<PersonAgeGroup> GroupPersonsByAge(List<Person> persons)
{
    return persons.GroupBy(x=>x.Age)
                         .Select(x=> new PersonAgeGroup
                                   {
                                      Age= x.Key, 
                                      Persons = x.ToList()
                                   }).ToList();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `PersonAgeGroup` directly in your LINQ. Also you need to return the results, not `null`:

```
public IList<PersonAgeGroup> GroupPersonsByAge(List<Person> persons) {
    var results = from person in persons
                  group person by person.Age into ages
                  select new PersonAgeGroup { Age = ages.Key, Persons = ages.ToList() };
    //Tip: use the "ToList" extension method to convert an IEnumerable to a List
    return results.ToList();
}
```

Some programmers like to combine the two lines into one:

```
public IList<PersonAgeGroup> GroupPersonsByAge(List<Person> persons) {
    return (from person in persons
            group person by person.Age into ages
            select new PersonAgeGroup { Age = ages.Key, Persons = ages.ToList() }
           ).ToList();
}
```